# Toggle width animation through jQuery while applying bootstrap class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to apply animation while changing a DIV's class through jQuery from `"col-lg-8"` to `"col-lg-12"`

Here is the line of jQuery code that I am using to change the class name, I just like an animation of expand of width to happen while the class name change.

```
$(".slide-content").toggleClass("col-sm-8 col-sm-12");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [css3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to do that like

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(".slide-content").toggleClass("col-sm-8 col-sm-12");
  })
});
```

```css
.slide-content {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="slide-content col-sm-8">asdfasd</div>
  </div>
  <button>Test</button>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o87pp10n/3/embedded/result/)